# Clustered app - only one server at a time reads from kafka, what am I missing?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I have a clustered application built around spring tooling, using kafka as the message layer for the fabric. At a high level, its architecture is a master process that parcels out work to slave processes running on separate hardware/vm's.

```
Master
   |_______________
   |       |      |
slave1  slave2 slave3
```

What I expect to happen is, if I throw 100 messages at Kafka, each of the slaves (three in this example) will pick up a proportionate number of messages and execute a proportionate amount of the work (about 1/3rd in this example).

What really happens is a slave picks up all of the messages and executes all of the work. It is indeterminate which slave will pick up the messages, but it is guaranteed one a slave starts picking up messages, the others will not until the slave has finished its work.

To me, it looks like the read from Kafka is pulling all of the messages from the queue, rather than one at a time. This leads me to believe I missed a configuration either on Kafka or in the Spring kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss a conceptual understanding what is Apache Kafka and how it works.

There is no queues, first of all. Messages are settled in the topic. Everybody subscribed can get the same message. However there is a concept of *consumer group*. So, independently of the number of subscrbibers, only one of them will read a single message if the consumer group is the same.

There is another feature in Kafka called *partitions*. With that you can distribute your messages into different partitions or they will be assigned automatically: evenly by default. This partitions feature has another angle to use. When we have several subscribers for the same topic in the same consumer group, the partitions are distributed between them. So, you may reconsider your logic in favor of built-in features in Apache Kafka.

There is nothing to do from the Spring Kafka perspective, though. You only need properly configure your topic for reasonable number of partitions and provide the same consumer group for all your "slaves".

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: As a practical rather than theoretical note - if messages are not keyed, then an optimization in kafka to reduce the number of open sockets uses only one partition at a time, balancing over time (10 minutes is the figure used in answers in other forums). To get round robin or balanced behavior at the message level, the messages must be keyed.